# Browser requests to the token endpoint must use Proof Key for Code Exchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, okta-api

I am getting the error "**Browser requests to the token endpoint must use Proof Key for Code Exchange**" when trying to post the following request from my code. But the same is working from the postman. Am I missing anything here?

```
  const urlEncodeData = qs.stringify({
            grant_type: "client_credentials",
            client_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            client_secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            scope: Scope,
        });
        const headers: any = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          
        };

        const tokenData = await axios.post(
            `${issuer}/v1/token`,
            urlEncodeData,
            headers
        );
```

I tried using qs and urlsearchparams and nothing worked.

Comment: It seem you are using client side application authorization method, but in postman you are sending server side authorization method.

Answer (score 1):

For client side application you are using and you should use PKCE Flow. Postman works because you are testing implicit flow, not the PKCE flow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that `client_credentials` flow assumes that you will be initiating a call to `/token` endpoint from a back-end server and not from your browser. So it might be an additional security check on Okta side, to discourage the use of inappropriate mechanisms/solutions